# Synchronize two drag-able tables

Tags: 6, javascript, theming

I have two tables on a page that the row positions need synchronized when a row is drug. One table is the master table and is the only place that the actual dragging can take place.

Basically, what needs to happen is when the user drags a row in the master table, the changes in position need to be duplicated to the child table.
I've been poking around with the `onDrop` custom handler function, but I am about at my wits end.
I'm not willing to hack tabledrag.js, as my custom module will be deployed on a system that I don't manage.

I'm sure someone else has faced this same issue. Are there any suggestion for a solution?

Comment: Back up a little, what are you trying to do in the bigger sense? You may be better served with a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module? If so, you can set the child table to use the sort order of the dragged table, and possibly trigger an ajax refresh when the order of the master table is saved.